# metadata-extractor class file unable to import in java class

Tags: java, maven, metadata-extractor

I am using metadata-extractor to extract geo location from images but class file of metadata-extractor unable to recognise in java class, while all the classes are showing in maven lib.

> Maven dependency

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.drewnoakes</groupId>
        <artifactId>metadata-extractor</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>javaxt</groupId>
     <artifactId>javaxt-core</artifactId>
     <version>1.8.1</version>
   </dependency>
```

> Java import classes

```
import com.drew.imaging.ImageMetadataReader;
import com.drew.imaging.ImageProcessingException;
import com.drew.lang.GeoLocation;
import com.drew.metadata.Metadata;
import com.drew.metadata.exif.ExifSubIFDDirectory;
import com.drew.metadata.exif.GpsDirectory;
```

[image]

Comment: What "repositories" do you have in your pom.xml? You might need to add one for "com.drewnoakes"

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? You appear to also have an issue with the `GeotagImages` class, which is not part of metadata-extractor.

Comment: @DrewNoakes No, I was not able to resolve, so I used javaxt 
 and GeotagImages class is part of javax

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your POM details. The package is available on Maven Central so should be picked up fine. Can you post some more information please?